# Store data between action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What the best way to store data between two controller action?

**Example:**

1. I have a big array of posts id `["2907", "2334", "2309",.... N]` i create it in first step confirm and go to second step to another controller action.
2. Another controller action render  data (calendar, groups), i select date in calendar, choose group and  create one more array of date-time data confirm and go to another action
3. Another action manipulate with this array and array of posts id, and render date again the data what i whant to save after confirm, data safe in DB and clear all array from session.

I store all array between action in session like `session[:posts_ids] = params[:posts_ids]` and `flash[:date_day] ||= params[:date_day]`. I think it do not work for a really big data array. May be the best way store it in redis ?

Answer (score 4):

This is largely opinion-based, but I think your two best options are:

1. Use Redis, Memcached or some other server-side cacheing solution to store the objects in memory until you need them.
2. Make your app more ajax-y and do all of the selection and temporary
   persistence of those arrays client-side.

Session size is limited by the underlying strategy, rather than a hard limit for sessions in general. CookieStore is the default and will allow ~4k of data, because browser cookies are limited to that size. If you use database-backed sessions, you're only limited by your database server.

You should also keep in mind that using sessions to store data between requests isn't very RESTful.